# Is it better practice to maintain specialised log tables or calculate number of entries with each sql

Tags: mysql, performance

I've been looking through some open source projects such as SMF forums etc and noticed that it incorporates specialised log tables that store just what seems like counts of boards, member, topics and even search results.

Currently in my projects I don't use such tables at all and instead make use of `SQL_CALC_ROWS` or `COUNT` in order to get total number of entries for a search query etc. I'm assuming that this is a bit of an over head on its own and was wondering if using log tables are an effective solution or is it vice versa.

Likewise I also have used the same method in a web application which could do with a speed boost. What are the overheads in executing specialised sql queries using `GROUP_CONCAT, COUNT` etc as opposed to setting up a program to automatically update a numeric count in a certain table when required.

For example if on one page I need to show statistics like number of members, number of classifeds entry and last active users - I normally execute a `SQL_CALC_ROWS` + `FOUND_ROWS` in mysql.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using COUNT is inherently slow as by definition it requires counting all rows, and usually this requires a full scan. It can therefore by advantageous to cache this result for performance reasons.

Note that this violates normalization and can lead to slight inconsistencies if the cached value isn't updated every time the data changes, but if performance is a real concern it can be worth it.

For example, if you are doing a search and you want to show 'Results 1-10 out of 105,000' it is often more important that results are returned quickly than the total numbers of rows is exactly correct.

Comment: So basically that means that everytime a user makes an addition or a deletion that means making an extra query to update a latest count value in a log table.

Comment: It depends. For instance it is very fast with MyISAM tables, as the row count is stored. I believe other engines know how to optimize COUNTs too, and manage to execute them using only indexes.

Comment: Well for a regular listing the count is kinda fixed understandabley but what about with respect to dynamic searches, where the search criteria are variable.

Comment: @Ali: The MyISAM cache of the row count is only useful without any search criteria. If you have a WHERE clause then it will need to count the rows again. But the WHERE clause itself may be able to use an index, in which case it might be possible to count only the matching rows in the index rather than doing a full scan of the table.

Comment: So the idea is to have indexes et up especially for fields that would be part of an expected search criteria. But aren't there space issues with setting up too many indexes. For now I have a database with over 100'000 entries and was wondering what steps could I take to ensure speedy retrieval.

Comment: @Ali: Here is some information about how MySQL can use indexes: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysql-indexes.html (note that COUNT is conspicuous in its absence from that page). Yes there are some space issues, but *usually* performance is more important than space concerns (disk space is cheap).

Comment: So as long as I've got my tables indexed right I probably don't need to go to the hassle of creating specialised log tables amirite here?

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Mark, if tables are large enough it can be really slow to count every time. Depending on how up to date stats you want you can chose from some approaches. Like update stats everyday, than stats wont be accurate all the time but its probably least costly option. Another possibility is recalculate stats when you are changing dataset. But if there are lots of inserts/deletes this might get slow.